# Display images on a JSP page through a servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am trying to display images in a Jsp page using Jstl, and image paths are passed on by a servlet. The Jsp page actually displays only one of the retrieved images and throws a NullPointerException.

The Jsp looks like this:

```
<c:forEach items="${images}" var="img">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="displayImg?imageId=${img.imageId}">
    </div>
</c:forEach>
```

And servlet doGet method looks like this:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    int imageId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("imageId"));
    Image img = imageDao.getImageById(imageId);
    response.setContentType("image/" + img.getImageType());

    File f = new File(img.getImagePath());
    BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(f);
    OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(bi, img.getImageType(), out);
    out.close();
}
```

I can't understand why this servlet manages to serve one image and fails on others with a NullPointerException when the request parameter is correct. I have an impression like it is a concurrency issue because the Jsp displays arbitrary image.

Any help please?

Here is the DAO:

```
public Image getImageById(int imageId) {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE imageId=?";
        Image img = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            connection = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
            ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
            ps.setInt(1, imageId);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            if (rs.next()) {
                img = new Image();
                img.setImageId(rs.getInt("imageId")); //NPE thrown here
                img.setImagePath(rs.getString("imagePath"));
                img.setImageType(rs.getString("imageType"));
                ...
                img.setDescription(rs.getString("description"));
                img.setCreatedOn(rs.getTimestamp("createdOn"));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            close(rs);
            close(ps);
            close(connection); //Removed this and problem disappears
        }
        return img;
    }
```

Solved!!
It is weird but I just avoided closing the connection to the database and all my images are displaying correctly with no errors. I guess closing the connection after every single DB access is problematic as it could not close at the exact time you want it to but maybe in the middle of another call to the DB. Now I wonder, not closing the connection at all is problematic too. What to do in that case?

Comment: Stack trace, please. ;-) Also, is it the JSP or the image servlet that throws the NPE?

Comment: @haraldK at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.buildIndexMapping(ResultSetImpl.java:674)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.findColumn(ResultSetImpl.java:1029)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getInt(ResultSetImpl.java:2566)
 at be.kayiranga.daoImpl.ImageDaoImpl.getImageById(ImageDaoImpl.java:114)
 at be.kayiranga.controller.ImageDisplayer.doGet(ImageDisplayer.java:32)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)

Comment: @haraldK NPE is comming from down the DAO. The Jsp and Servlet seem both fine. But still, I suspect the problem lies in how and when invocations to business code are done.

Comment: Pro tip: Don't answer comments asking for details. Update the question instead. This will help new readers understand your problem. :-) Also, I think you haven't posted the relevant code. Most likely, it's something in your DAO.

Comment: @haraldK Just did as you said!!!

Comment: How are you saving image in the database and in the model? Where is your stacktrace and JSP? Are you trying to display an image which is a byte[]? I would recommend using a string to display image. I am posting some code as answer presuming you are using byte[] in model. Also, where is the imageId coming from, why do you need to use ParseInt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weird as `imageId` is used as column name in the query, and there is a record, `rs.next()`.
Maybe it is not an int but long, or SQL VARCHAR.
Maybe MySQL was so overly clever to leave out imageId as this was specified in the WHERE?
Or somehow in this case you need to use `rs.getInt("images.imageId")`.

```
            img.setImageId(rs.getInt("imageId")); //NPE thrown here
```

could however be written (circumvented) as

```
            img.setImageId(mageId);
```

I would check that there is no devious typo: `í` (accent), Cyrillic `e` (if you are East European) or tab char. Honestly said your code looks neat, but similar errors happen with much less neat code: ps, ps2, rs, rs2 as fields, playing havoc with concurrent uses and apt to typos.

BTW writing could be done faster with less memory resources:

```
Path path = Paths.get(img.getImagePath());
OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
Files.copy(path, out);
```

---

***On the search for errors:***

Investigating the error seems the only option:

```
ResultSetMetaData meta = rs.getMetaData();
int numberOfColumns = meta.getColumnCount();
for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfColumns; ++i) {
    log(... i, meta.getColumnName(i), meta.getColumnLabel(i) ...);
}
```

Comment: It is fine if I write img.setImageId(imageId), but then the NPE moves to the next line as if the ResultSet is not null but has an empty row.

Comment: imageId is for sure an int. I am using a local mysql db.

Comment: I have added code on the result set results. Really weird. Must be something simple.

Comment: I investigated with your code snipet and everything is fine about rs metadata. This is very weird though, I have three images to test with and the Jsp will display one or two or all images every time I run the app and completely arbitrary. When some of the images are not displayed, I get a NPE of course.

Answer (score 0):

Just read the stack trace:

```
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.buildIndexMapping(ResultSetImpl.java:674)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.findColumn(ResultSetImpl.java:1029) 
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getInt(ResultSetImpl.java:2566) 
at be.kayiranga.daoImpl.ImageDaoImpl.getImageById(ImageDaoImpl.java:114)
```

So, the exception is thrown by

```
rs.getInt("imageId")
```

which means that there is no column named `"imageId"` in the result set.

You should never use `select *`. Use explicit column names, and use these explicit column names when getting data from the result set:

```
select imageId, imagePath, imageType, description, createdOn from ...
```

Comment: If the column was not there I would have seen it in the stackTrace that I purposefully print. So the column is right there because one image happens to be retrieved and displayed successfully, which couldn't happen if there was an issue whatsoever with the DAO. Tried removing * and putting column names with exactly same result.

Answer (score 0):

THis answer might not help you completely, as no one I believe understands what you are doing exactly. I am presuming you have a JSP page and a form inside, I can show you how to display the image as a string.

```
public showImage(){
  BASE64Encoder base64Encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
 // your method to retreive the image
 if(image == null){
   File imagePath = new File("/home/akshay/images.jpeg"); // display alternate image
      try {
          BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(imagePath);
          ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", byteArrayOutputStream);
   //Below person is the main object model, and String is the image in string
        person.setProfilePhotoString("data:image/png;base64," +   base64Encoder.encode(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
  } else{
         person1.setProfilePhotoString("data:image/png;base64," +  base64Encoder.encode(person1.getProfilephoto()));
}
}
```

JSP page :

```
<form:form action="${showAction}" commandName="person">
    <table>
 <tr>
            <td><img src= "${person.profilePhotoString}"  height=100 width=100/>
        </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: I actually have my images stored on my server such that: C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.15\webapps\userdirs\rmedardo_xPn6HH. I only store paths other details in the DB, so no bytes.

Comment: Ok, then you can modify the code above and use it...I am sure it will work. Just get the image as a byteArrayoutputstream, and use the setter method for the string.